# Open Urls in new tabs from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to coding and have spent the last few days trying to figure out the following:

I have a google docs spreadsheet with URLs in column K. I would like to add a script to the spreadsheet that reads column K and each time the script finds a URL opens the URL in a new tab.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks. Rich

Answer (score 1):

not possible.

Google Apps Script in spreadsheets is executed on Google's servers, it can not tell your browser to open a new tab or window without a user explicitly doing some action (in other words, clicking the url).